# I get null on the first request to firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

When I click on the button I send a message, then the message listener goes off and gives me an error because the returned value from the field date = null , I write the server time in date using @ServerTimeStamp , but if I reopen the fragment with chat all messages will be displayed normally

```
database
        .collection(KEY_COLLECTION_USERS)
        .document(preferenceManager.getString(KEY_USER_ID)!!)
        .collection(KEY_COLLECTION_CHAT)
        .addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
            var messages_test = ArrayList(messages)
            if (error != null) {
                return@addSnapshotListener
            } else {
                if (value == null) {
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                } else {

                    for (documentChange in value.documentChanges) {
                        if (documentChange.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                            var doc = documentChange.document
                            if (doc.getString(KEY_MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID) == receiverUser.uid) {
                                var text = doc.getString(KEY_MESSAGE).toString()
                                var id = doc.getString(KEY_MESSAGE_ID).toString()
                                var receiverId =
                                    doc.getString(KEY_MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID).toString()
                                var date = doc.getTimestamp(KEY_MESSAGE_DATE)?.toDate()

                                var isChecked = doc.getBoolean(KEY_MESSAGE_ISCHECKED)!!
                                var type = doc.getString(KEY_TYPE_MESSAGE).toString()
                                var message =
                                    Message(text, id, receiverId, date, isChecked, type)
                                if (message !in messages) {
                                    messages.add(message)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    messages.sortBy { it -> it.date }
                    var messages_test = ArrayList(messages)
                    userChatAdpater.updateList(messages_test)
                    if (messages.size != 0) {
                        mBinding.rvUserChat.smoothScrollToPosition(messages.size - 1)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This is message listener

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo in `var date = doc.getTimestamp(KEY_MESSAGE_DATE)?.toDate()` i get null value when I send a message, but when messages are just loaded when I re-enter the chat snippet everything works fine, I think that ServerTimeStamp does not have time to load when I call the listener

Comment: Yes, it takes some time until the Firebases server generate the timestamp.

Comment: @AlexMamo But now I don't know how I should listen to the messages properly.

Comment: @AlexMamo I solved the problem, thank you very much. i use this `var date = doc.getTimestamp(KEY_MESSAGE_DATE,DocumentSnapshot.ServerTimestampBehavior.ESTIMATE)?.toDate()`

Comment: @AlexMamo Unfortunately, this solved the problem partiall `ServerTimestampBehavior.ESTIMATE`  returns a local value